# Finding limit of multivariable function.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I have a question that might be silly but I need to understand these kind of problems. So i have this limit:$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3 + y^3}{x^2 + y^2}$$
To solve it I am going to use poolar coordinates, so the limit would be like this:

$$\lim_{r\to0} \frac{r^3\cos^3\theta + r^3\sin^3\theta}{r^2}=$$
$$\lim_{r\to0} {r(\cos^3\theta + \sin^3\theta)}$$

Now it is clear to me that r tends to $r\to0$ but, can I actually say something about $\cos^3\theta + \sin^3\theta?$
In case I could, then I would say that it is bounded, thus the limit would be 0. But it is not clear to me, could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because

$$\left|\cos^3\theta + \sin^3\theta\right| \le \left|\cos\theta\right|^3 + \left|\sin\theta\right|^3 \le 2$$

Also without polar coordinates:

\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right| &= \frac{|x+y||x^2-xy+y^2|}{x^2+y^2} \\
&\le|x+y| \cdot \frac{x^2+y^2+|xy|}{x^2+y^2} \\
&\le \sqrt{2}(x^2+y^2) \cdot \frac{\frac32(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\\
&= \frac{3\sqrt{2}}2\|(x,y)\|^2 \xrightarrow{(x,y) \to (0,0)} 0
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Both cosine and sine are always bounded by $1$ in absolute value.  Therefore, 
$|\cos^3 \theta + \sin^3 \theta| \leq 2$.  Your limit is therefore $0$.

Comment: If you consider the graph of $\cos^3\theta + \sin^3\theta$ it lies between -1 and +1

Comment: Yes, two is just an upper bound.  Any constant is sufficient for this problem.

Comment: Would it be true to say that the limit is zero from all directions?

Comment: Yes, as 2 is a uniform bound for all theta.

Comment: Yes, I think there is a proposition that says that if you change to polar coordinates, and you are left with two functions, one bounded and the other tending to cero, then the limit of the function in all directions is 0. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$
\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=
\frac{x^2+y^2-xy}{x^2+y^2}(x+y)=x+y-\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}(x+y)
$$
Now observe that
$$
\left|\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le1
$$
because $a^2-ab+b^2\ge0$.